# performance issue with canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a drawing class i have created that has some performance issues.  I imagine it has to do with the way i am handling the drawing actions and undo/redo functions.  Can anyone offer some advice as to how to improve the performance?

```
public class KNDrawingSurfaceView extends View {

    private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
    private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;
    public Bitmap mBitmap;
    public Canvas mCanvas;
    public Path mPath;
    public Paint mBitmapPaint;   
    float myWidth;
    float myHeight;
    public Paint mPaint;
    public MaskFilter mEmboss;
    public MaskFilter mBlur;
    public ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    public ArrayList<Paint>paints = new ArrayList<Paint>();
    public ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>(); 
    public ArrayList<Paint>undonePaints = new ArrayList<Paint>();

    private KNSketchBookActivity _parent;

    public KNDrawingSurfaceView(Context c, float width,float height, KNSketchBookActivity parent) {
        super(c);
        myWidth = width;
        myHeight = height;
        _parent =parent;
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);

        mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 }, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);

        mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);

        mPath = new Path();

        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)myWidth, (int)myHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        Log.v("onDraw:", "curent paths size:"+paths.size());
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        Paint tile = new Paint();

        Bitmap tileImage =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.checkerpattern);
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(tileImage, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        tile.setShader(shader);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, myWidth, myHeight, tile);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        for (Path p : paths){
            canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(mPath,mPaint);
    }

    public void onClickUndo () { 

        if (paths.size()>0) 
        { 
           undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size()-1));
           undonePaints.add(paints.remove(paints.size()-1));
           invalidate();
         }
        else
        {

        }
         _parent.checkButtonStates();
    }
    public void onClickRedo (){
        if (undonePaths.size()>0) 
        { 
            paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size()-1));
            paints.add(undonePaints.remove(undonePaints.size()-1));
            invalidate();
        } 
        else 
        {

        }
        _parent.checkButtonStates();
     }
    public void onClickClear (){
        paths.clear();
        undonePaths.clear();
        invalidate();
        _parent.checkButtonStates();
     }
    public void saveDrawing(){


        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        String fileName = "tempTag";
        try {

            outStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/" + fileName + ".png");

            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
            outStream.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }


    }
    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        undonePaths.clear();
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);

        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

        paths.add(mPath);
        paints.add(mPaint);
        _parent.checkButtonStates();
        mPath = new Path(); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        if(x>myWidth){
            x=myWidth;

        }
        if(y>myHeight){
            y=myHeight;

        }
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

please share with me any experience or links you may have dealing with drawing/canvas optimization

Comment: You are creating a bitmap every time you are on onDraw()  and as far as I can see is always the same bitmap.  Create it only once just use it on onDraw(). Bitmaps can be an expensive resource.

Comment: move this mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)myWidth, (int)myHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap); to  onSizeChanged

Comment: i tried your code on my device. it works fine. i made few changes do you want me to post the code?

Comment: canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR); why do you have this in your onDraw(). every time you call invalidate() it will refresh your draw

Answer (score 2):

Use the below for reference and modify the below according to your requirements.

You have the below in onDraw()

```
 canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
 // will clear the draw
```

Everytime you can invalidate() will call onDraw(canvas). Your draw will be refreshed.

I don't know what you are trying to do but i removed the above

Moved the inside onSizeChanged

```
   mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)myWidth, (int)myHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
   mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
```

Your code works fine. Tested it on emulator.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

DrawingView dv ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dv = new DrawingView(this);
    setContentView(dv); 
}

public class DrawingView extends View {

    private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
    private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;
    public Bitmap mBitmap,tileImage;
    public Canvas mCanvas;
    public Path mPath;
    public Paint mBitmapPaint;   
    float myWidth;
    float myHeight;
    Paint tile ;
    public Paint mPaint;
    public MaskFilter mEmboss;
    public MaskFilter mBlur;
    public ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    public ArrayList<Paint>paints = new ArrayList<Paint>();
    public ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>(); 
    public ArrayList<Paint>undonePaints = new ArrayList<Paint>();
    BitmapShader shader;

    public DrawingView(Context c) {
        super(c);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        tile = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
        mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 }, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
        mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        tileImage =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        shader = new BitmapShader(tileImage, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT); 
        tile.setShader(shader);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);    
        myWidth =w;
        myHeight = h;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        Log.v("onDraw:", "curent paths size:"+paths.size());
        for (Path p : paths){
            canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(mPath,mPaint);
    }

    public void onClickUndo () { 

        if (paths.size()>0) 
        { 
           undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size()-1));
           undonePaints.add(paints.remove(paints.size()-1));
           invalidate();
         }
        else
        {

        }

    }
    public void onClickRedo (){
        if (undonePaths.size()>0) 
        { 
            paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size()-1));
            paints.add(undonePaints.remove(undonePaints.size()-1));
            invalidate();
        } 
        else 
        {

        }

     }
    public void onClickClear (){
        paths.clear();
        undonePaths.clear();
        invalidate();

     }
    public void saveDrawing(){


        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        String fileName = "tempTag";
        try {

            outStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/" + fileName + ".png");

            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
            outStream.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }


    }
    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        undonePaths.clear();
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);

        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

        paths.add(mPath);
        paints.add(mPaint);

        mPath = new Path(); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        if(x>myWidth){
            x=myWidth;

        }
        if(y>myHeight){
            y=myHeight;

        }
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't allow screen orientation so i didn't put that bitmap code in the on sizeChange, i also needed it for my undo and redo buttons in the parent activity that allow users to undo/redo their drawing actions...  but this was all good advice.. posting the my solution now

Comment: Your onSizeChanged will be called when the size of the view changes. So you can move the code mentioned to that method

Answer (score 1):

You are recreating 2 bitmaps, paint and BitmapShader in onDraw() method. This is causing your performance issues.
try this:
- move object creations to constructor.
- i think that you can remove this part completely:

```
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)myWidth, (int)myHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
```

(if you need to get bitmap from your canvas, create separate method for that and call it when needed)

Comment: @erik you can create a bitmap and draw the same in ondraw. but you need not initialize everytime and draw the bitmap on canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Do not create or instantiate any variable on your "loop", do that before and outside onDraw and reuse the same variables. This will surely increase performance!

Answer (score 1):

As you all suggested i pulled all my var initiations out of onDraw and put them in the constructor.

This particular piece is needed to clear the canvas when the user undoes or redoes something they have drawn:

```
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) myWidth, (int) myHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
```

so i created a new method that i just call on undo/redo:

```
public void clearCanvasCache() {

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) myWidth, (int) myHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }
```

Works great now..

The Whole class:

```
public class KNDrawingSurfaceView extends View {

    private static final float MINP = 0.25f;

    private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;

    public Bitmap mBitmap;

    public Canvas mCanvas;

    public Path mPath;

    public Paint mBitmapPaint;

    float myWidth;

    float myHeight;

    public Paint mPaint;

    public MaskFilter mEmboss;

    public MaskFilter mBlur;

    public ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();

    public ArrayList<Paint> paints = new ArrayList<Paint>();

    public ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();

    public ArrayList<Paint> undonePaints = new ArrayList<Paint>();

    private KNSketchBookActivity _parent;

    Paint tile;

    Bitmap tileImage;

    BitmapShader shader;

    public KNDrawingSurfaceView(Context c, float width, float height, KNSketchBookActivity parent) {

        super(c);

        myWidth = width;
        myHeight = height;

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) myWidth, (int) myHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

        _parent = parent;
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);

        mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 }, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);

        mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
        tile = new Paint();

        tileImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.checkerpattern);
        shader = new BitmapShader(tileImage, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        tile.setShader(shader);

        mPath = new Path();

        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {

        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Log.v("onDraw:", "curent paths size:" + paths.size());
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, myWidth, myHeight, tile);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        for (Path p : paths) {
            canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    public void onClickUndo() {

        if (paths.size() > 0) {
            undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
            undonePaints.add(paints.remove(paints.size() - 1));
            clearCanvasCache();
            invalidate();
        } else {

        }
        _parent.checkButtonStates();
    }

    public void onClickRedo() {

        if (undonePaths.size() > 0) {
            paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size() - 1));
            paints.add(undonePaints.remove(undonePaints.size() - 1));
            clearCanvasCache();
            invalidate();
        } else {

        }
        _parent.checkButtonStates();
    }

    public void onClickClear() {

        paths.clear();
        undonePaths.clear();
        clearCanvasCache();
        invalidate();
        _parent.checkButtonStates();
    }

    public void saveDrawing() {

        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        String fileName = "tempTag";
        try {

            outStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/" + fileName + ".png");

            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
            outStream.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }

    }

    private float mX, mY;

    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {

        undonePaths.clear();
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {

        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {

        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);

        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);


        paths.add(mPath);
        paints.add(mPaint);
        _parent.checkButtonStates();
        mPath = new Path();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (!_parent.isDrawerOpen()) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            if (x > myWidth) {
                x = myWidth;

            }
            if (y > myHeight) {
                y = myHeight;

            }
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void clearCanvasCache() {

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) myWidth, (int) myHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your onDraw method is still not 100% optimized.

This is the "issue":
You are drawing mBitmap (which has all paths drawn on it) and after that you draw again all paths from paths array.
Thing is, you dont need to draw paths from array if you're already drawn mBitmap. (only case when you have to redraw paths from arrays to mBitmap is when you click undo or redo)

Comment: also in your method clearCanvasCache()
you dont need to recreate bitmap and canvas, just redraw color to it like this:
mCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

Comment: This works great ! I came to this post while searching for how to improve performance of my application which involves recording path when user is writing text. I have tried different strategies but after 3 lines there was a significant lag and text was losing the smoothness. I integrated your solution into mind and voila ! its perfect now :)